# Replacement for tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model in Tensorflow v2

Tags: tensorflow

The below code is from http://shzhangji.com/blog/2018/05/14/serve-tensorflow-estimator-with-savedmodel/

The tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model is deprecated in Tensorflow version 2. Can someone please help me to write the below prediction without using the tf.contrib.predictor

```
# Load model from export directory, and make a predict function.
predict_fn = tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model(export_dir)

# Test inputs represented by Pandas DataFrame.
inputs = pd.DataFrame({
    'SepalLength': [5.1, 5.9, 6.9],
    'SepalWidth': [3.3, 3.0, 3.1],
    'PetalLength': [1.7, 4.2, 5.4],
    'PetalWidth': [0.5, 1.5, 2.1],
})

# Convert input data into serialized Example strings.
examples = []
for index, row in inputs.iterrows():
    feature = {}
    for col, value in row.iteritems():
        feature[col] = tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[value]))
    example = tf.train.Example(
        features=tf.train.Features(
            feature=feature
        )
    )
    examples.append(example.SerializeToString())

# Make predictions.
predictions = predict_fn({'inputs': examples})
# {
#     'classes': [
#         [b'0', b'1', b'2'],
#         [b'0', b'1', b'2'],
#         [b'0', b'1', b'2']
#     ],
#     'scores': [
#         [9.9826765e-01, 1.7323202e-03, 4.7271198e-15],
#         [2.1470961e-04, 9.9776912e-01, 2.0161823e-03],
#         [4.2676111e-06, 4.8709501e-02, 9.5128632e-01]
#     ]
# }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/load
There is a detailed guide here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#loading_and_using_a_custom_model